# Attribute class dont work

Tags: c#, attributes

I have this simple program, the problem is that the code never reaches TestClassAttribute class. The console output is:

```
init
executed
end
```

The Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("init");
        var test = new Test();
        test.foo();
        Console.WriteLine("end");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public class TestClassAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public TestClassAttribute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AttrClass");
            Console.WriteLine("I am here. I'm the attribute constructor!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [TestClass]
        public void foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("executed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never construct an instance of `TestClassAttribute`, e.g. with `new TestClassAttribute()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably read up on [How do attribute classes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676603/how-do-attribute-classes-work).

> They aren't instantiated when you create an object that they are applied to, not one static instance, not 1 per each instance of the object. Neither do they access the class that they are applied to..
>
> You can try to get the list of attributes on a class, method, property, etc etc.. When you get the list of these attributes - this is where they will be instantiated. Then you can act on the data within these attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes don't do anything by themselves. They are not even constructed *before* one asks for attributes on particular class/method.

So to get your code to write "AttrClass" you need to ask for attributes of `foo` method explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are lazily instantiated. You have to get attribute in order to constructor be called.

```
var attr = test.GetType().GetMethod("foo")
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute), false)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no. Attributes are **special**. Their constructors aren't run until you use reflection to get to them. They don't **need** to run then. For example, this small method reflects into the attribute:

```
public static string RunAttributeConstructor<TType>(TType value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute), false);
}
```

You'll see wherever you call this in your `Main` the constructor for the attribute will run.