# Alternative for MethodInterceptionAspect

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I need to limit some function regarding license . so i created an attribute using MethodInterceptionAspect in postSharp and validate the fields i need. 
is there any other 3rd party making aop custom attributes ? 
i know dynamic proxy is exist but i want the annotation part also.

Example :

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class LicenseValidator : MethodInterceptionAspect
    {
        readonly String name;

        public LicenseValidator(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            if (name = ! "notInvoke")
            {
                args.Proceed();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not executed !");


        }
        }
}
```

And the usage of this :

```
[LicenseValidator("tal")]
public static Boolean PrintHi(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    return true;
}
```

NOTE : it's just an example for the usage and isn't my code. but this is the method i want to use in order to solve my problem.

Any other way to achieve it with attributes? 3rd party or manually.

Thanks !

Comment: Method Interception using Reflection in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165707/method-interception-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use other 3rd party such Spring.NET, Castle Windsor, Aspect.NET and etc.
or you can use Ioc Container such as  Unity or StractureMap and etc.

```
PostSharp is CompileTime and other are runTime.
```

and also can use `AspectInjector` .
It is very simple and also `CompileTime` like postSharp .

You can see this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118339/Yet-Another-Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Framework) to how to use it.

I hope it will be useful