# Changing attribute value of an object in an ObservableCollection overwrites attribute vale of other objects in the same collection

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

Am having a class as following,

```
class Person
{
   private string _PersonName;

   [Category("General")]
   [ReadOnly(true)]
   [Browsable(true)]
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _PersonName; }
       set { _PersonName= value; }
   }
}
```

and an `ObservableCollection` of `Person` objects as following,

```
ObservableCollection<Person> Persons =  new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

Consider, I am having 5 `Person` objects in `Persons(ObservableCollection)`.

```
Person Person1 = new Person(){Name = "User 1";}
Person Person2 = new Person(){Name = "User 2";}
Person Person3 = new Person(){Name = "User 3";}
Person Person4 = new Person(){Name = "User 4";}
Person Person5 = new Person(){Name = "User 5";}

Persons.Add(Person1);
Persons.Add(Person2);
Persons.Add(Person3);
Persons.Add(Person4);
Persons.Add(Person5);
```

Now, am changing `Browsable` attribute value of Second object from `true` to  `false` dynamically as follows,

```
PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Person1)["Name"];
BrowsableAttribute ba =(BrowsableAttribute)pd.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)]; 
FieldInfo IsBrowsable = ba.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
IsBrowsable.SetValue(ba, false);
```

after this change, value of `Browsable(true)` attribute of all other objects becomes `false`.

This is the problem, How to prevent this?

Thank you all.

Comment: `Persons.Add(new Person().Name = "User5");` doesn't look right at all. Instead try `Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "User5" });`

Comment: What makes you think you are "changing Browsable attribute value of Second object"? There is no Person instance involved in your code.

Comment: AFAIK, attributes are applied at the aspect level (e.g. Class, Method, Property, etc) and not at the 'object' level. When you change the attribute value, it's applied for the Name property of Person class (which means for all instances/objects of Person). See ['How do attribute classes work'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676603/how-do-attribute-classes-work)?

Comment: @publicgk Thank you very much for this clarification. Is there any way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @publicgk I want each person object with different browsable attribute value for its Name property.

Comment: And where do you intend to use this value?

Comment: @publicgk in propertygrid

Comment: Nopes. can't be done for individual objects.