# Value of a CustomAttribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm trying to understand how custom attributes work.
I have the following code (Which is mostly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2677415/6474510) SO answer):

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before class constructor");
        var test = new TestClass();
        Console.WriteLine("after class constructor");

        Attribute[] attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(test.GetType()); 
    }
}

public class TestClassAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestClassAttribute()
    {
        Second = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine("I am here. I'm the attribute constructor!");
    }
    public String First { get; set; }
    public String Second { get; set; }
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("MyFirst: {0}; MySecond: {1}", First, Second);
    }
}

[TestClass(First = "customized")]
public class TestClass
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on `Main`'s last line, and using the debugger I dived into the source code until the `TestClassAttribute` constructor got called (happens inside the `unsafe` overload of `CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes`). Once passed the constructor's first line, I have the following content on the Locals window:

[image]

Questions:

1. Why `this`'s value is the value that gets returned from `ToString`?
2. `MyFirst` has no value. On what moment it will [*EDIT*: i.e., what method in `System.CustomAttribute` initializes this property]? (Couldn't see it happening with the debugger, I don't know why).

Comment: You aren't setting First in the constructor like you are for Second: Second = "hello";

Comment: With your edited code, after the last line MyFirst should have "customised" as value.

Comment: @αNerd, Chad, I edited my second question.

Answer (score 0):

`ToString` is really designed (read: was designed) as a debugging tool and that is why it shows up as the local value in the Locals window.

It appears that any names parameters to an attribute are assignments *after* the constructor is run. Loosely this is how I think the compiler interprets that:

```
TestClassAttribute instance = new TestClassAttribute();
instance.First = "customized";
```