# Is there a way to invalidate the ASP.NET MVC 3 ActionCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates, asp.net-mvc-views

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses custom attributes to create select controls for model properties that can be populated from external data sources at runtime.  The issue is that my `EditorTemplate` output appear to be cached at the application level, so my drop down lists are not updated when their data source changes until the Application Pool is recycled.

I also have output the contents of the MVC 3 `ActionCache` that is bound to the `ViewContext.HttpContext` object as shown in the MVC 3 source code in System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.cs:95.

- Action Cache GUID: `adf284af-01f1-46c8-ba15-ca2387aaa8c4`:
- Action Cache Collection Type: ``` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers+ActionCacheItem] ```
- Action Cache Dictionary Keys: `EditorTemplates/Select`

So it appears that the `Select` editor template is definitely being cached, which would result in the `TemplateHelper.ExecuteTemplate` method to always return the cached value instead of calling `ViewEngineResult.View.Render` a second time.

**Is there any way to clear the MVC ActionCache or otherwise force the Razor view engine to always re-render certain templates?**

For reference, Here are the relevant framework components:

```
public interface ISelectProvider
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList();
}

public class SelectAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private readonly ISelectProvider _provider;

    public SelectAttribute(Type type)
    {
        _provider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(type) as ISelectProvider;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
    {
        modelMetadata.TemplateHint = "Select";
        modelMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add("SelectListItems", SelectList);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return  _provider.GetSelectList();
        }
    }       
}
```

Next, there is a custom editor template in `~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Select.cshtml`.

```
@model object
@{
    var selectList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["SelectListItems"];
    foreach (var item in selectList) 
    {
        item.Selected = (item != null && Model != null && item.Value.ToString() == Model.ToString());
    }
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s, selectList)
```

Finally, I have a view model, select provider class and a simple view.

```
/** Providers/MySelectProvider.cs **/
public class MySelectProvider : ISelectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList()
    {
        foreach (var item in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test.txt"))
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem() { Text = item, Value = item };
        } 
    }
}

/** Models/ViewModel.cs **/
public class ViewModel
{
    [Select(typeof(MySelectProvider))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

/** Views/Controller/MyView.cshtml **/
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

** **EDIT** **

Based on suggestions in the comment, I started to look more closely at the `ObjectContext` lifecycle.  While there were some minor issues, the issue appears to be isolated to an odd behavior involving a callback within a LINQ expression in the `SelectProvider` implementation.

Here is the relevant code.

```
public abstract class SelectProvider<R, T> : ISelectProvider
  where R : class, IQueryableRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly R repository;

    public SelectProvider(R repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList(Func<T, SelectListItem> func, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var ret = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (T entity in repository.Table.Where(predicate).ToList())
        {
            ret.Add(func(entity));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList();
}


public class PrinterSelectProvider : SelectProvider<IMyRepository, MyEntityItem>
{
    public PrinterSelectProvider()
        : base(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyRepository>())
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList()
    {
        // Create a sorted list of items (this returns stale data)
        var allItems = GetSelectList(
            x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.DisplayName,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            },
            x => x.Enabled
        ).OrderBy(x => x.Text);

        // Do the same query, but without the callback
        var otherItems = repository.Table.Where(x => x.Enabled).ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.DisplayName,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text);

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Query 1: {0} items", allItems.Count()));
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Query 2: {0} items", otherItems.Count()));

        return allItems;
    }
}
```

And, the captured output from the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` is

```
Query 1: 2 items
Query 2: 3 items
```

I'm not sure what could be going wrong here.  I considered that the `Select` may need an `Expressions`, but I just double-checked and the LINQ `Select` method only takes `Func` objects.

Any additional suggetions?

Comment: This should only be an issue within the context of a single HTTP request. The action cache is stored in HttpContextBase.Items, which ["is used to share data between a module and a handler during an HTTP request"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.items.aspx). Can you provide an actual implementation of ISelectorProvider? Is it possible you are caching model metadata or the SelectList data?

Comment: You are right. I've confirmed that my simplified example works as posted.  I'm attempting to isolate the issue further.  Our project uses EntityFramework to query from a database and Ninject as the DI framework.

Comment: Have you verified that you are using the correct (per-request) object scope for your DbContext?

Comment: It was not, but now the DbContext is being created as .InRequestScope(), but is being disposed of early in some place. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the difference between repository.GetTable() and repository.Table?

Comment: Just a bad copy-and-paste.  I was cleaning up code as I worked through the previous issue.  `GetTable()` was the old method and was replaced with a `Table` getter property.  Both just returned an `ObjectSet` from the `ObjectContext` as an `IQueryable<T>`. I've updated the code in question.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, have you profiled the SQL that is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I finally had a chance to re-visit this issue.  The root cause had nothing to do with `LINQ`, the `ActionCache`, or the `ObjectContext`, rather it was related to [when attribute constructors are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run).

As shown, my custom `SelectAttribute` class calls `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` in its constructor to create an instance of the `ISelectProvider` class.  However, the ASP.NET MVC framework scans the assemblies for custom metadata attributes once and keeps a reference to them in the application scope.  As explained in the linked question, accessing a `Attribute` triggers its constructor.

So, the constructor was run only once, rather than on each request, [as I had assumed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91350/what-should-every-programmer-know/91486#91486).  This meant that there was actually only one, cached instance of the `PrinterSelectProvider` class instantiated that was shared across all requests.

I solved the problem by changing the `SelectAttribute` class like this:

```
public class SelectAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private readonly Type type;

    public SelectAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        // Instantiate the select provider on-demand
        ISelectProvider provider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(type) as ISelectProvider;

        modelMetadata.TemplateHint = "Select";
        modelMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add("SelectListItems", provider.GetSelectList());
    }
}
```

Tricky problem indeed!