# Logging Exception using Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to log exception for all of my methods using AOP. I had created an attribute for the same as following:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
 public class ClsLogger : System.Attribute
 {
    private string _exMsg;
    public ClsLogger(string exMsg)
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        _exMsg = exMsg;
        LogError();
    }
    public void LogError()
    {
        // This methods logs exception
        // Log Exception
    }
}
```

Finally, I want to use this logging attribute to log exception messages of the methods of my application. How I can pass exception messages to the atrribute as it is not a fixed string but varrible?
Could anybody help on this?

Comment: `You should always add the suffix Attribute to custom attribute classes.` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w875ab50(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: probably good practice, but it is not strictly necessary

Answer (score 1):

Attributes in C# don't instantiate until you call `GetCustomAttributes`, and they instantiate every time you do so ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run) here on SO).

If you want to use AOP (as your title indicates), then you'll need to use some framework, like [PostSharp](http://postsharp.net), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), [SheepAspect](http://sheepaspect.codeplex.com/), etc.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, then there is a built-in `ActionFilter` class that you can also use, but only on Controller methods.