# Import and run external method levering c# custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

so because of an odd performance issue we currently need to run a windows form and force it to act like a console project. not really a problem and this is working fine while the third part looks into the performance issue.

when you do this,

```
Console.WriteLine("something")
```

does not actually print out to the console.

Solution for that was adding the following (found on a bunch of SO posts)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern bool AttachConsole(int processId);
```

then call that method in the Main

```
            AttachConsole(-1);
```

ok this works fine, still need to see if this ends up causing the same performance issue that originally prompted us to use a windows form solution in the first place TBD.

Being that i do not want to have to copy this code into every project (Booooo), I created a [custom Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and added that code to it.

```
public class FormOnConsol : Attribute
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole(int processId);

    public FormOnConsol(int processid = -1)
    {
        AttachConsole(processid);
    }
}
```

cant seem to figure out why that is not working when used like

```
    [STAThread]
    [FormOnConsol]
    static void Main()
    {
          //some fun code here
          //naturally because all code is fun =]
    }
```

any point in the right direction is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor of attribute will be activated only if you query it. See more info on this topic here: [when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run)

P.S. It is not right to use attributes for any active actions. It should be used merely for declarative purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will look into it. Was kinda an excuse to make an attribute and just seemed like a non-obtrusive way to include this. happen to have a recommendation for a better way to approach this? guess i could just make a base class that does this, just seems "cleaner" to have it be an attribute.

Comment: Yes, using base class is more natural way for that.