# How to GC collect Attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, attributes

I want to release all the attribute's from memory.

*Which reference I have to break so these attributes will get cleaned from memory?.*

I'm not finding any references at all with these attributes in my application but still they are not releasing.

```
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class AttributeEx : System.Attribute
    {
        ....
    }
```

***Reference Chain :***
[image]

Comment: You might as well ask how to force your _code_ to be garbage-collected. The attributes are an integral part of your assembly; GC is for data dynamically-allocated at run-time.

Comment: Yes @PeterDuniho... Understood.. then, How can I remove them from memory?

Comment: Why are you concerned about it? Use a memory profiler and find who holds the references of the attributes.

Comment: Answer: See comment of @PeterDuniho above

Comment: @PeterDuniho Instances of an attribute *are* dynamically allocated at runtime, just like any other type.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I did that with ANTS Memory Profiler and I have not  found any releation's with these attributes...

Comment: @dcastro Not all attributes. For example security attributes are loaded by CLR itself. Not sure if it keeps a reference to it (it shouldn't though )

Comment: @dcastro: thanks...maybe I misunderstand the question, as the attribute _instances_ that are returned (e.g. via reflection) seem obviously GC-able to me. I figured the OP was asking about the attribute descriptions in the IL. Maybe the question just isn't clear enough for me to understand it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Please check the reference chain...

Answer (score 3):

> Which reference I have to break so these attributes will get cleaned from memory?.

Instances of attributes are created *only* when you inspect them, not when you create instances of types decorated with those attributes. E.g.

```
var attrs = typeof(ClassWithAttribute).GetCustomAttributes();
```

So long as `attrs` is a local variable, the attribute will have a really short lifespan and soon be eligible for garbage collection.

Note that these attributes are instantiated *each and every time* you call `GetCustomAttributes`.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes exist in GC memory only when you ask for them (see for example [When is a custom attribute's constructor run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run)):

```
[Obsolete]
public class MyClass
{

}

// Here the ObsoleteAttribute is created
var att1 = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttributes(false)[0];

// Here the ObsoleteAttribute is created again
var att2 = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttributes(false)[0];

// false!
bool refeq = object.ReferenceEquals(att1, att2);
```

So if you don't ask for them, they aren't created. And even when you ask for them, they can be GC collected when they aren't referenced anymore (so after the `bool` line in this case)