# How to force construct certain custom attribute?

Tags: c#, .net

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run), attribute constructor will not run until `GetCustomAttributes()` method is called.
This will instantiate every attributes owned the class.
What is the most efficient way to force construct a certain custom attribute ? Upon new-ing the class, I only want to instantiate specific attributes, not all of them.

```
[RegularAttribute("Dont_turn_me_on_yet")]
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [SpecialAttribute("On_RightAway_Please")]
    public void MethodOne(){}

    [RegularAttribute("Dont_turn_me_on_yet")]
    public void MethodTwo(){}
}

static void Main()
{
   var mc = new MyClass(); //SpecialAttribute constructor is called right away, but not RegularAttribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding what attributes are. Attributes are *metadata*, they're stored in the assembly as a kind of recipe for an object:

- Used attribute's constructor metadata token
- Positional parameters' values
- Property setters values

That's it. No more, no less.

When you call `GetCustomAttributes` on a member, the runtime will instantiate this member's attributes with the *recipe* stored in the metadata, and handle you that.

You get a fresh instance on each call, as attribute instance are just classes, and therefore are *mutable*. Doing so ensures you get the true metadata. If you have performance issues with this, just cache them yourself, and make sure you don't alter them.

Comment: Right. Thank you for the theory behind it. I am looking for a way to work around it. It is similar to the way Microsoft does it with their CAB's EventBroker subscription. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edjez/archive/2005/04/20/cabeventbroker101.aspx

Comment: They don't do it magically either: *"The attributes are there for simplifying the dev experience - they get processed **whenever an instance of the class that has them gets added to a WorkItem or the Host** in CAB."*. While you could design a base class which would instantiate the attributes of its derived class upon its construction, I think you've got a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271659) here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. GetCustomAttributes is able to get certain attributes by type. This code below will not instantiate the RegularAttribute. It needs to be called in either base constructor or `[InjectionMethod] in Unity DI.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = (typeof(MyClass)).GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SpecialAttributeAttribute), false);
}
```

More efficient answer is welcomed.