# Are attributes always executed before methods in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have an attribute before a method definition in C#, is this attribute always executed before the method starts running? I've been researching for the past hour but couldn't find any concrete information on this.

Comment: Attributes an sich don't actually do anything -- they're just metadata. It depends on what you (or a framework) are doing with the attribute.

Comment: @daremkd You mean the Attribute's contructor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have an attribute before a method definition in C#, is this attribute always executed before the method starts running?

No, it's not guaranteed at all. In fact, the usual behavior of the runtime seems to be that the attribute's constructor is run only when the attribute is requested (via reflection on the decorated member). As far as I can tell, only the attributes of the `Main` method are actually run without manual reflection.