# In C# [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)] Is not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

While creating a custom attribute of "AttributeTargets.Parameter" constructor is not called. I want to use the parameter value of Fn function under Test Class. I used .net core and .net standard.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.Fn("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine("end");
        Console.Read();
    }
}


public class Test
{
    public void Fn([Parameter] string parm)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parm);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class ParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ParameterAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Parameter Attribute");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember, **Attribute** constructors are only executed when you start inspecting the type and not when an instance of that type is created or a method executed (in your case).

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168535/when-is-a-custom-attributes-constructor-run) answer for a detailed example of the order of execution when using custom **Attributes**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Itay,
When I used my custom Attribute as a class attribute it's working fine but when I set Usage target To Parameter it stops working. I am trying to get the parameter value of the attribute.

Comment: Take a look at [ParameterInfo.Attributes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo.attributes?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) on how to extract method parameters' attributes (there's an example in that link that shows exactly how it is done).