# get all types in assembly with custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Is there an elegant way to get all the types in an assembly that have a custom attribute?

So if I have a class

```
[Findable]
public class MyFindableClass
{}
```

I would like to be able to find it in a collection of types returned by Assembly.GetTypes(...)

I can do it with a big vile hack, but I'm sure someone has a nicer way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're considering a "big vile hack", but if it is a simple for loop, it isn't a hack; it's a good solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - how enumerate all classes with custom class attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607178/c-sharp-how-enumerate-all-classes-with-custom-class-attribute)

Comment: Important corollary question How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I wouldn't think you can dodge enumerating every type in the assembly, checking for the attribute, but you could use LINQ to make the query easier to understand:

```
Assembly assembly = ...
var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(FindableAttribute))
            select type;
```

EDIT: Moved from `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes` to `Attribute.IsDefined` based on Marc Gravell's suggestion.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Attribute.IsDefined(type, attribType) would be more efficient here

Comment: Might be type.IsDefined(attribType) - in which case, my mistake http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx

Comment: @Marc: I checked; this exists too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.isdefined.aspx

Comment: Was working on something similar today and din't occur to me to use LINQ for it.  Very nice!