# Finding custom attributes in assembly wierdness

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, unity-game-engine

Why does the following work to find classes that are using my custom attribute but,

```
    Assembly [] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach(Assembly a in assemblies)
    {
        foreach(Type t in a.GetTypes())
        {
            object [] attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestingAttribute), false);
            foreach(object o in attributes)
            {
                Debug.Log(o is TestingAttribute);
            }
        }
    }
```

this method and similar ones I've found on StackOverflow do not. This code is executed in Unity3d. The result is empty.

```
    Assembly [] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach(Assembly a in assemblies)
    {
        var attributes = a
                   .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestingAttribute), false)
                   .Cast<TestingAttribute>();
        foreach(TestingAttribute t in attributes)
        {
            Debug.Log(t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely the 2nd example is retrieving the attributes of the assembly itself, whereas the first enumerates the types in the assembly and gets those *types* that have that attribute...?

Comment: In that case is there any way to say "get all the custom attributes used in an assembly" or do you have to pull the custom attributes of every individual class?

Comment: I don't think so. There is a neat solution using Linq [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852879/get-all-types-in-assembly-with-custom-attribute) though: