# How to determine which .net unit test framework a project is using?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I've inherited a visual studio 2017 solution that has a unit test project included. The only project reference that look test related to testing is Microsoft.Owin.Test. The tests include TestClass and TestMethod attributes (defined in microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting)

So, does this mean I'm using MSTest or ?

I'm trying to track down a problem where a test class that inherits another test class won't run the inherited tests when I try to run that tests for that class directly (right click: run tests in class). They run fine from Test Explorer. Seems first I need to determine if I'm using nunit, mstest, or...

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Related post - [How can I check if project is a Test Project? (NUnit, MSTest, xUnit)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20152371/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of tests framework that we can write our test cases based on them.

> (For example: MsTest, NUnit, xUnit.net)

Anyway, in your case, the MsTest is the framework that was used in the project you are work in. You can easily find out that by its namespace which refers to `Microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting`

Please visit the following links for more information:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on those links, it seems "Visual Studio test engine" and "MsTest" synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the nunit.framework.dll in your project references, and by the description it seems not, you are using the Visual Studio test engine.