# BDD - should each scenario be self contained?

Tags: bdd

I have a BDD feature containing multiple scenarios. Should each scenario be completely self contained and runnable individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Should be*, yes. It is generally good practise in all forms of TDD (BDD included) to make sure that each "test" can run independently, and isn't coupled with or have a dependency on another test having been run first. This will help avoid creating a brittle test suite (i.e. one that is prone to breaking).

That's not to say that you cannot chain readability together. For a very cheap/quick example:

```
Feature: Users can register and log in


Scenario: Should be able to register
Given I am not registered
When I complete the registration form
Then I will be registered

Scenario: Should be able to log in
Given I am registered
When I correctly sign-in with my credentials
Then I will be logged in

Scenario: Should be able to log out
Given I am logged in
When I sign-out
Then I will be logged out
```

Each scenario indicates a test that can be automated - and each should be designed behind the scenes to be able to run independently. But as a reader of the feature (say a business stakeholder) - the process is complete and they can understand the entire picture more easily.

Comment: I notice your scenarios repeat having the word "should" in them. Is this a convention of BDD? I've heard of this but thought the word "should" should be placed in the feature description. And can you explain why this convention exists or point to a source that explains it?

Comment: It may be a convention - I think that I've read that it was a conventions somewhere too...; but in all honesty I couldn't say for sure. Really the 'convention' is to express the name of the scenario in whatever way best explains it's intent to all the interested parties (devs, testers and stakeholders). 'Should' works well in my mind because it explains that something 'should' happen. It is easily read, easily understood and easily flows into a sentence. Sorry that I cannot give a more concrete answer!