# Run SpecFlow scenario from code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow

I am trying to run a SpecFlow scenario from code instead of through Test Explorer or the command line. Has someone managed to do this?

From a scenario, I can extract the method name and test method with recursion, but I cannot run this scenario method. It seems to need a proper initialize and teardown, but I could't manage to do this.

My first thought was to use the `TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner` class, but it doesn't seem to have a scenario selection method.

**EDIT** on why I want to do this:
We want to run specific scenarios from TFS. It is very cumbersome to connect TestMethods to WorkItems in TFS, because:

- You can only assign one testmethod to one workitem
- For each workitem you have to search the method name, with in itself is a hassle, because the list is very long with lots of specflow scenarios.
- When your specflow scenario gets a different name (which happens a lot), TFS cannot find the correct method anymore
- Specflow Scenario Outlines get practically unusable, while they are a very powerful feature.

I want to create a mechanism where each automated workitem gets the same method assigned. This method extracts the workitem id and search and executes the scenario(s) with this workitem tagged.

Comment: I think it is a bit tricky to get a scenario running from code since you have to setup a testrunner environment which - I think - could be a bit complex.
Can you briefly explain what you want to achieve by doing this? Maybe there is a more simple way to solve your problem instead of running a Scenario by code.

Comment: @realtime, thank you for asking, I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Sorry, this currently runs a bit off-topic. But I do not get the sense behind connecting WorkItems to TestMethods. If I have a WorkItem, it addresses a certain bug, maybe a feature i want to have. Then I want to have an isolated test case which addresses exclusively this issue. This alone helps in traceability a lot! An single test case is (in my world) equal to a feature file. So I connect features (or files) to WorkItems. Changes of Scenario Names do not care anymore and you have a lot less trace-connections to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem since my tests have some dependencies between Scenarios (shame on me, but it saves tons of copy-paste lines per Feature file). In most cases I would stick to isolated Scenarios of course.

I used reflection

1. [Find all Types with a DescriptionAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607178/how-enumerate-all-classes-with-custom-class-attribute) (aka Features)
2. Find their MethodInfos with a TestAttribute and DescriptionAttribute (aka Scenarios)
3. Store them to a Dictionary
4. Call them by "Title of the Feature/Title of the Scenario" with Activator.CreateInstance and Invoke

You have to set the (private) field "testRunner" according to your needs of course.