# How does this factory function manage to resolve the "Factory" object automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, factory

So I'm currently looking at some code and I'm trying to figure out how this line manages to resolve the "factory" which apparently is nothing but a delegate that takes a "Type" and returns an object. It's hard for me to form this question because I don't fully understand what's going on. Could someone break it down?

It all starts in the `App.cs`

```cs
public App()
{
    IServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();
    _services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
    _services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();

    /* This is the part I don't understand */
    _services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavService>(sp =>
    {
        return new NavService(type => sp.GetRequiredService(type));
    });
    ...
    _serviceProvider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

This essentially builds the singleton instance that we're registering

```cs
    _services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavService>(sp =>
    {
        return new NavService(type => sp.GetRequiredService(type));
    });
```

And we're passing in whatever `sp.GetRequiredService(type)` returns as a parameter to the `NavService` constructor.
Which seems to be a `Func<Type, object>`? Why?
And what is `type` that we're using when we're using the lambda statement `type => sp.GetRequiredService(type)`

How do we resolve a  `Func<Type, object>` from `type` ?

Inside the `NavService` we're utilizing that delegate by invoking it with a type, which I believe resolves the singleton instance of whatever type we're using when calling `NavigateTo<T>`

```cs
public class NavService : ObservableObject, INavigationService
{
    private readonly Func<Type, object> factory;
    private object _currentView;
    public NavService(Func<Type, object> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get => _currentView;
        private set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void NavigateTo<T>() where T : ViewModel
    {
        object viewModel = factory.Invoke(typeof(T)) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate VM.");
        CurrentView = viewModel;
    }
}
```

So my best guess is that, what we pass in through the constructor is the actual "factory" behind the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package that I'm using which is responsible for newing up instances of dependencies that we're registering.
But that still doesn't answer my question of how we resolve a  `Func<Type, object>` from `type`  which is just of type `Type`?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an inline lambda as delegate. The delegate is the used as a factory to create instances dynamically.

When you have the following constructor...

```cs
class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
  public NavigatioService(Func<Type, object> factory) 
  {}
}
```

...then you must register a related factory delegate in order to be able to construct it with a DI container. The factory delegate in the above example takes a parameter of type `Type` and returns an instance of  type `object`.

The `factory` delegate translates to the following lambda expression:

```cs
typeParameter => factory_implementation_that_returns_object;
```

Instead of instantiating the type manually you can use the service provider to instantiate it for you. This will automatically create all required dependencies:

```cs
// Create a delegate that takes a Type as parameter and returns an object using the ServiceProvider
type => sp.GetRequiredService(type)
```

Now for some reason you have decided to create the `NavigationService` instance explicitly (`new NavigationService()`). As a drawback you also have to explicitly build all the constructor dependencies, which is the `Funcy<Type, object>` delegate:

```cs
// Register the INavigationService and tell the IoC container how to build this type
_services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavService>(sp =>
{
  
  // Imagine NavService had more constructor dependencies!
  // Imagine even this single dependency had 10 dependencies itself, 
  // where each has n dependencies, where each has...
  // You would find yourself to take care to satisfy all of them explicitly at this point...
  return new NavService(type => sp.GetRequiredService(type));
});
```

Instead of registering the `Func<Type, object>` as a regular dependency, you decided to create this delegate manually inline. This is not a good decision. You always want he IoC container to wire up the dependencies for you.

I don't recommend to do it this way (inline). It only works when the constructor has a single parameter and this parameter doesn't requests its own dependencies. Otherwise you would have to construct all constructor dependencies manually (inline) - which is definitely not what you want.

Additionally, it's also better (more robust) to return an explicit type instance from the factory instead of `object`.
Because you have defined the `Navigate` method as generic with a type constraint that `T` must be of type `ViewModel`...

```cs
// The type of T is used as the parameter for the factory delegate
public void NavigateTo<T>() where T : ViewModel
```

...you should use `ViewModel` as the explicit return type of your factory.

To improve your code, the goal is to let the IoC container do all the work. That's what it is for. As a bonus, the code becomes simpler and the configuration feels more intuitive.
The key is to design your code that you don't have to create the `NavService` instance manually. For this reason you should try to use a parameterless factory delegate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75056968/3141792) (solution #2) to get an example on how to design the `Navigate` method. There are good design reasons to not allow every page to navigate to any page. The idea is to let the caller pass in the reference instead of the `Type` (and instantiate this `Type` in the `NavService`). Just do it like the `Frame` does it.

However, to fix and improve your example you simply have to register the factory delegate as a service. This way you don't have to create it inline and you don't have to create the receiving type manually too:

```cs
class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
  private Func<Type, ViewModel> Factory { get; }
  public ViewModel CurrentView { get; private set; }

  // Improve the robustness and use a strongly typed result (of type ViewModel).
  // The Type parameter of the delegate is later provided by the caller, which is the Navigate method.
  public NavigatioService(Func<Type, ViewModel> viewModelFactory) 
  {
    this.Factory = factory;
  }
    
  // The type of generic type parameter 'TViewModel' 
  // is the parameter for the factory delegate
  public void NavigateTo<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModel 
  {
    ViewModel viewModel = this.Factory.Invoke(typeof(TViewModel));
    this.CurrentView = viewModel;
  }
}
```

```cs
public App()
{
  IServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();
  _services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
    .AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>()

    // Let the IoC contaiiner construct the NavigatioService
    // and all its dependencies for you
    .AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigatioService>()

   // Register the factory delegate as normal dependency, 
   // so that the IoC container can resolve it
    .AddSingleton<Func<Type, ViewModel>(serviceProvider => viewModelType => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(viewModelType));
    
    _serviceProvider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And we're passing in whatever sp.GetRequiredService(type) returns as a parameter to the NavService constructor.

No you aren't.

You are passing in a lambda `type => sp.GetRequiredService(type)` to the constructor. This lambda is the factory method.

The dotnet runtime doesn't have any direct support for lambda's. Instead the C# compiler will translate your code into IL that is equivalent to;

```cs
public class Captures{
    private IServiceProvider sp;
    public Captures(IServiceProvider sp){
        this.sp = sp;
    }
    public object Factory(Type type){
        return sp.GetRequiredService(type);
    }
}

_services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavService>(sp =>
    {
        var captures = new Captures(sp);
        return new NavService(new Func<Type,object>(captures.Factory));
    });
```

So when `NavService` executes `factory.Invoke`, the generated method `Captures.Factory` will be called, which will in turn call the extension method `sp.GetRequiredService` to obtain the instance of the requested `Type`.